# Grails - Check where a parameters came from (GET, POST, or Forward)

Tags: grails, post, parameters, get, forward

Is it possible in Groovy/Grails to check where a parameter found in the params map came from?  For example, was it sent as a GET parameter, a POST parameter, or was it simply forwarded via the forward() method in another controller?

Comment: Not easily. First, forward() uses GET. Secondly the HttpServletRequest specification already combines both POST and GET into parameters. In order to do what you are looking to do you would have to write your own ServletFilter to read the inputStream (since it's not re-readable as a default implementation) and build some extra request data that stores the difference between GET and POST parameters. It could be done, but why is it important? Maybe you can address the issue you are facing another way.

Comment: As far as forward goes, you could always just stick something in the request object whenever you do a forward in a controller... http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html  

I'm not certain about get and post though.